# Restrict Azure DevOps Self Hosted Agent to run for 1 JOb

Tags: azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We have deployed self-hosted agents on Docker Image managed by Azure Container Images. We run release jobs parallelly and hence want to restrict the use of 1 agent for 1 job. The agent should either restart or delete after completion

Answer (score 0):

In the release pipeline, you can set Demand for the job to specify a specific agent to run.

Demands: Specify which capabilities the agent must have to run this pipeline.

[image]

Or you can add an additional job, use the hosted agent to run the job, add a powershell task to this job, and delete the self-hosted agent that has finished running the job by calling the [Agents-Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest api

```
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{poolId}/agents/{agentId}?api-version=6.0
```